# How to script sync & migration operations using Sequelize for node.js and Heroku Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

The [Sequelize example](http://sequelizejs.com/heroku#adding-sequelize-app-js) suggests doing this just before `server.listen()` in `app.js` which seems too limiting.

How would you script more complex syncs or migrations?

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization new project with DB is one-time process before starting the project. DB or synchronized with the application or not, so do not input your synchronization code in Express. Create standalone separate `sync.js` file with all your `models` and sync code  and run it before you run your Express app.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(... {
  // dbs settings    
});

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
   name: Sequelize.STRING
});

var Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    body: Sequelize.STRING
});

Post.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Post);


User.sync({force: true}).success(function() {
    Post.sync({force: true}).success(function() {
        console.log('Everything was synchronized');
    });
});
```

And after that run you Express app